# Send Cookie Using Python Requests

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data (reproduce a POST operation I did in a browser) by using Python Requests library. Expecting it will return the content I saw while using browser by copying the `request header` and `post form`.

However, I am not quite sure what is the correct way to send cookies using Python Requests. 
Here is a screen shot how it looks like in Chrome.

It looks like I can either use cookie as a key in the request header or use the cookie argument in the post command.

(1). If I want to use cookie in the request header, should I treat the whole cookie content as a long string and set the key to be `cookie` and set the value to be that string?

(2). If I want to use the cookie argument in the `request.post` command, should I manually translate that long string into a dictionary first, and then pass to cookie argument?. Something like this?

```
 mycookie = {'firsttimevisitor':'N'; 'cmTPSet':'Y'; 'viewType':'List'... }
 # Then 
 r = requests.post(myurl, data=myformdata, cookies=mycookie, headers=myheaders)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. But make sure you call it "Cookie" (With capital C)
2. I always did it with a dict. Requests expects you to give a dict.

A string will give the following

```
cookiejar.set_cookie(create_cookie(name, cookie_dict[name]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: quick question, if you have a field with numeric value, say `content-length` is `200`. When you create the headers, should we treat them as numeric or string?

Comment: Headers are send as chars (string), so treating them as strings will be the right way the go. But I don't know whether the requests library has any problems with it.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies):

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/cookies'
>>> cookies = dict(cookies_are='working')

>>> r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
>>> r.text
'{"cookies": {"cookies_are": "working"}}'
```

So use a dict for cookie, and note it's `cookies` not `cookie`.